# How to Run headless Netlogo 5.2.1 form the command line in Windows 7

Tags: windows, netlogo, headless

I am trying to run headless Netlogo from windows and I have not been able to figure out how to run it, I am new at using have form the command line.

I looked at:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

and

http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Running-NetLogo-Headless-in-Behaviorspace-Sample-code-td4862232.html

and I could not figure it out

I used cd C:\Program Files (x86)\NetLogo 5.2.1 and then within that I tried:

```
~/netlogo-5.2.1/netlogo-headless.sh \
```

That did not work, also I tried

```
org.nlogo.headless.Main
```

and

```
org.nlogo.headless
```

can you guy tell me what to do?

thanks